# Скрыть слои div через интервал

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется блок, который нужно скрывать в категории товаров, родительский класс в каждой категории имеет свой id например product-category-999 Подскажите как скрыть содержимое класса в родительской категории например всех категорий от 1до999. Просто не хочется нумеровать все 999 значений в стиле. Скрываю я слой вот так

```
body.product-category-999 .block {display:none; }
```

```html
<body class="product-category-999">
    <div class="panel ocfilter panel-default" id="ocfilter">
        <img class="block" src="/image/main/rotate.php" alt="" width="160px">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы там за костыли строите... Вы могли бы хоть как-то объяснить что вы скрываете и зачем?

Comment: скрываю я на всех страницах категорий, т.к эта картинка предназначена для фильтра на главной. На главной странице родительский класс совершенно другой. Писать в css для каждой родительской категорий не хочется т.к категорий очень много

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через **JS**.

```js
    function hideBlocksInside(className, from, to) {
       for(let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
               let block = document.querySelector(className + i + " .block");
           block.style.display = "none";
       }
    }
        
    hideBlocksInside(".product-category-", 1, 3);
```

```html
<div class="product-category-1">
    <p class="block">
     Hello-1
    </p>
</div>

<div class="product-category-2">
    <p class="block">
     Hello-2
    </p>
</div>

<div class="product-category-3">
    <p class="block">
     Hello-3
    </p>
</div>
```

На странице должен быть только один тег **body**. Вот с вашей структурой, но **div** вместо **body** (для наглядности поставил задержку скрытию):

```js
function hideBlocksInside(className, from, to) {
    for(let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        let block = document.querySelector(className + i + " .block");
        if(!block) continue;
        block.style.display = "none";
    }
}

setTimeout(hideBlocksInside, 5000, ".product-category-", 1, 999);
```

```html
<div class="product-category-120">
    <div class="panel ocfilter panel-default" id="ocfilter">
        <img class="block" src="https://18.img.avito.st/640x480/5200844318.jpg" alt="" width="160px">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-category-228">
    <div class="panel ocfilter panel-default" id="ocfilter">
        <img class="block" src="https://18.img.avito.st/640x480/5200844318.jpg" alt="" width="160px">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-category-871">
    <div class="panel ocfilter panel-default" id="ocfilter">
        <img class="block" src="https://18.img.avito.st/640x480/5200844318.jpg" alt="" width="160px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё равно отображает

Comment: Посмотрите на пример, который я добавил. Я не видел вашей структуры, поэтому не могу точно понять, что у вас по-другому.

Comment: Структура примерно такая
<body class="product-category-120">
<div class="panel ocfilter panel-default" id="ocfilter">
<img class="block" src="/image/main/rotate.php" alt="" width="160px"> 
</div>
</body>

Comment: Снова добавил пример.

Comment: супер, всё работает